# Python - Beautiful Soup OR condition in soup.find_all(....)

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

We were scrapping Amazon.in website to retrieve the price of any product. All products are having different value for 'id' attributes in 'span' tag such as;

```
 id = 'priceblock_ourprice',  id = 'priceblock_saleprice', and  id = 'priceblock_dealprice'.
```

Our task is to retrieve the price of the products using the find_all(..) method in Beautiful Soup. From our basic knowledge we were able to give only one parameter to the find_all(..) method as shown below:

```
m = soup1.find_all('span', {'id': 'priceblock_ourprice'})
```

Is there any way to give multiple parameters to the find_all(..) method using OR condition?

Following are the links with different values of same 'id' attribute:

[Link 1](http://www.amazon.in/Samsung-Galaxy-Edge-Gold-Platinum/dp/B00UTGZ0GO)

[Link 2](http://www.amazon.in/Samsung-Galaxy-Black-Sapphire-32GB/dp/B00UTGYT0W)

[Link 3](http://www.amazon.in/Godrej-Fully-automatic-Top-loading-Washing-Machine/dp/B00LLYZCFM/ref=sr_1_1?s=kitchen&ie=UTF8&qid=1460777632&sr=1-1&keywords=washing+machine)

Thank you for your help!

Comment: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSECommerceService/latest/DG/EX_RetrievingPriceInformation.html

Comment: @jordanm Actually we are learning data scrapping and we are doing to understand its working.

Comment: Do you need to do it in one line, or could you just call `find_all` three times?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I haven't tested this but I believe you can pass a function as an argument to `find_all()` so you could try something like:

```
def check_id(tag):
    valid_ids = ['priceblock_ourprice','priceblock_saleprice','priceblock_dealprice']
    if tag.has_attr('id'):
        return tag['id'] in valid_ids
    else:
        return False

m = soup1.find_all(check_id)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. It worked. Could you please explain its working? What is the tag parameter doing and how id 'check_id' being called without any '()'. I am new to python. Thanks

Answer (score 4):

You can add your condition in your find_all parameters as follow :

```
td_tag_list = soup.find_all(
            lambda tag:tag.name == "span" and
            'id' in tag.attrs and tag.attrs['id'] == 'priceblock_ourprice')
```

Comment: If (like me) you are wondering about this lambda syntax, I found a really good explanation here: https://www.tomordonez.com/python-lambda-beautifulsoup/

Comment: I used this format in find for meta og:title which can have either a property or name attribute: `soup.find(lambda tag: tag.name == "meta" and (("property" in tag.attrs and tag.attrs["property"] == "og:title") or ("name" in tag.attrs and tag.attrs["name"] == "og:title")))`

Answer (score 3):

For those that wonder if they could avoid overcomplicating their script. simply passing a list inside the find statement works perfectly fine like so:

```
find_all(name='div', attrs={'class': 
[...
'one_sixth grey_block new-secondary-background result-item',
'one_sixth grey_block new-secondary-back', 
...]
```

Answer (score 0):

There is another way that I found it. You can pass a regex to an attribute.

```py
import re
ids = ['priceblock_ourprice', 'priceblock_saleprice', 'priceblock_dealprice']
m = soup1.find_all('span', {'id': re.compile(ids.join("|"))})
```